# Can't prove easy theorem $\emptyset \in F \rightarrow \cap F = \emptyset$.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

This is a problem from a book that teaches proof-writing basics. This is an exercise that assumes that I have sufficient knowledge to be able to solve the problem. But I feel stuck at this moment.

Assuming $F$ is a set of sets and $\cap F$ is the intersection of all members of $F$.

So far I've been able to rewrite the conclusion $ \cap F = \emptyset$ in terms of quantifiers. The idea being that there does not exist an $x$, such that $x \in \cap F$ (equivalent to $\forall S (S \in F \rightarrow x \in S)$). Then I bring the negation inside:
$$ \neg \exists x \forall S (S \in F \rightarrow x \in S),$$
$$ \forall x \neg \forall S (\neg S \in F \vee x \in S),$$
$$ \forall x \exists S \neg (\neg S \in F \vee x \in S),$$
$$ \forall x \exists S (S \in F \wedge \neg x \in S).$$

So now I have to prove that:
$$ \emptyset \in F \rightarrow \forall x \exists S (S \in F \wedge \neg x \in S).$$

Maybe there is a possibility to rewrite the hypothesis of the theorem $\emptyset \in F$ in terms of quantifiers, but I don't think I can do it.

I also tried to prove the contrapositive but it did not lead me anywhere, because I don't know how to arrive at $\emptyset \notin F$.

Comment: The $S$ you seek to satisfy the existential is just $\emptyset$.

Comment: That works too: $\bigcap_{f \in F} f = \emptyset \cap \bigcap_{f \in F \setminus \{ \emptyset \}} = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof with words.

Suppose the set $\cap F$ is not empty, so it contains some element $x$. This means that for every $A \in F$ we have $x \in A$. Applying this to $A = \emptyset \in F$ we have $x \in \emptyset$. That is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

By definition of $\emptyset$

$(\forall x)(x \notin \emptyset)$.

$\bigcap F = \emptyset$ means $(\forall x)(\exists S \in F)(x \notin S)$.

The existential quantifier of the latter statement is witnessed by $\emptyset$ which is an element of $F$. The latter statement is true.

Hence $\bigcap F = \emptyset$.